# How to use service-now Table API with Java?

Tags: java, servicenow-rest-api

I am using demo instance to query service-now. Using cURL works fine, but I want to use java to query the Table API. I have followed [this](https://docs.servicenow.com/integrate/inbound_rest/reference/r_TableAPIJavaExamples.html). I have provided my instance credentials and the instance name correctly. I get error like this:

```
$ javac GetAction.java
GetAction.java:6: error: package org.apache.http does not exist
import org.apache.http.HttpException;
                      ^
GetAction.java:7: error: package org.apache.http does not exist
import org.apache.http.HttpHost;
                      ^
GetAction.java:8: error: package org.apache.http.auth does not exist
import org.apache.http.auth.AuthScope;
                           ^
GetAction.java:9: error: package org.apache.http.auth does not exist
import org.apache.http.auth.UsernamePasswordCredentials;
                           ^
GetAction.java:10: error: package org.apache.http.client does not exist
import org.apache.http.client.CredentialsProvider;
                             ^
GetAction.java:11: error: package org.apache.http.client.methods does not exist
import org.apache.http.client.methods.CloseableHttpResponse;
                                     ^
GetAction.java:12: error: package org.apache.http.client.methods does not exist
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
                                     ^
GetAction.java:13: error: package org.apache.http.impl.client does not exist
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicCredentialsProvider;
                                  ^
GetAction.java:14: error: package org.apache.http.impl.client does not exist
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
                                  ^
GetAction.java:15: error: package org.apache.http.impl.client does not exist
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;
                                  ^
GetAction.java:16: error: package org.apache.http.util does not exist
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
                           ^
GetAction.java:19: error: cannot find symbol
        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, HttpException {
                                                                   ^
  symbol:   class HttpException
  location: class GetAction
GetAction.java:24: error: cannot find symbol
        public void getRequest() throws HttpException, IOException {
                                        ^
  symbol:   class HttpException
  location: class GetAction
GetAction.java:25: error: cannot find symbol
                CredentialsProvider credsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
                ^
  symbol:   class CredentialsProvider
  location: class GetAction
GetAction.java:25: error: cannot find symbol
                CredentialsProvider credsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
                                                        ^
  symbol:   class BasicCredentialsProvider
  location: class GetAction
GetAction.java:27: error: cannot find symbol
                new AuthScope(new HttpHost("xxxxxxxx.service-now.com")),
                    ^
  symbol:   class AuthScope
  location: class GetAction
GetAction.java:27: error: cannot find symbol
                new AuthScope(new HttpHost("xxxxxxxx.service-now.com")),
                                  ^
  symbol:   class HttpHost
  location: class GetAction
GetAction.java:28: error: cannot find symbol
                new UsernamePasswordCredentials("wwwww", "yyyyyy"));
                    ^
  symbol:   class UsernamePasswordCredentials
  location: class GetAction
GetAction.java:29: error: cannot find symbol
        CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom()
        ^
  symbol:   class CloseableHttpClient
  location: class GetAction
GetAction.java:29: error: cannot find symbol
        CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom()
                                         ^
  symbol:   variable HttpClients
  location: class GetAction
GetAction.java:34: error: cannot find symbol
            HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("https://xxxxxxxx.service-now.com/api/now/table/incident?sysparm_query=number%3DINC0000057&sysparm_limit=1");
            ^
  symbol:   class HttpGet
  location: class GetAction
GetAction.java:34: error: cannot find symbol
            HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("https://xxxxxxxx.service-now.com/api/now/table/incident?sysparm_query=number%3DINC0000057&sysparm_limit=1");
                                  ^
  symbol:   class HttpGet
  location: class GetAction
GetAction.java:37: error: cannot find symbol
            CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
            ^
  symbol:   class CloseableHttpResponse
  location: class GetAction
GetAction.java:41: error: cannot find symbol
                String responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
                                      ^
  symbol:   variable EntityUtils
  location: class GetAction
24 errors
```

How to make the documentation code work? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You need to add the relevant jar files to your buildpath and classpath

Comment: Add required packages first

Answer (score 0):

The error says that the mentioned dependencies are not present. You need to add jar file for package `org.apache.http`. If you are using maven, you can get the library from [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient/4.5.2).